# How to bind nested json objects to check boxes

Tags: angularjs

I have a user table  displaying there assigned Company(s). I would like to use checkboxes to edit them. I am using to sessionStorage to bind the properties when the user is selected on the table. I created a plunker. 
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3eKMmLiLCDzxmfrlhxdz?p=preview)

```
 <body ng-controller="controller1">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>UserName</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="selectUser(user)" style="cursor:pointer">
      <td>
        <font ng-repeat="company in user.Companies">{{company.CompanyName}}{{$last?'': ','}} </font>
        </td>
      <td>{{user.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.UserName}}</td>
      <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="year" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Company(s)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.Companies.CompanyName"> Black Elk </label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="main.check2"> Saratoga </label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="main.check2"> Three Rivers </label></div>
    </div>
 </div>
{{user.Companies[0].CompanyName}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that is the best way to go about it but if you really want to do it that way you could do this:

```
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="hasCompany(1)" ng-click="changeCompany(1)" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" > Black Elk </label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="hasCompany(2)" ng-click="changeCompany(2)" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" > Saratoga </label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline"> <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="hasCompany(3)" ng-click="changeCompany(3)" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" > Three Rivers </label></div>
    </div>



$scope.hasCompany = function(id){
   return false;// user.Companies contains the id. use underscore or lodash find;
 }
 $scope.changeCompany = function(id){
   return false;//if the company exists in the collection then remove it, else add it
 }
```

OR, if you want to upgrade to angular 1.3 and want to keep using ng-model you can use ng-model-options

http://plnkr.co/edit/HCwObn5m9RWd7yBOViKS?p=preview

Comment: Do I need to have lodash for the plunker to work? When I click on the first user the check boxes do not get populated.  If this isnt the best of doing this, what would you suggest

Comment: I have updated the plunker to be operational. When you click on the first user, the check boxes will be populated. I will leave it up to you to decide how the company is added to the user's company collection.